# Userprofiles without an accountid give you an Oops! Something bad happened

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, stack-overflow-for-teams

... but only if you are a member of one or more Stack Overflow for Teams.

Visit [this userprofile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7386033) for example. It doesn't have an accountid (found based on [this SEDE Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/957799)).

When you're in one (or more) Stack Overflow for Teams thingy's  you'll get an [Oops! Something bad happened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fF21r.png)

If you are not part of any SO for Teams you'll see [the user profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhRBP.png)

Confirmed by fieldtests in [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/44967988#44967988) and the [Tavern](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7468633#7468633)

It could be that the accountid being null is the root cause of the problem and rectifying that solves the problem but in anyway I would prefer being served the same result on the public parts of the site whether I'm in a team or not.

Can this be looked at?

Comment: Interesting. As a moderator, I can access our moderator-only view of the account, and I can access their developer story, but not the public areas nor their settings page!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A user without an account is an error condition - all users, even unregistered users, are *supposed* to have accounts even if that account is merely a stub awaiting registration.

However... Mistakes happen. Sometimes adding a new credential fails, or merges go horribly wrong, or simply creating the account itself falls apart - leaving a user orphaned. When this happens, it usually requires contacting support to resolve it - either the user will need to be merged, deleted and recreated, or a dev will have to manually connect up the account.

This should *not* result in an exception however - in fact, it's kinda hard to fix if viewing the profile blows up! A small bit of code made a bad assumption (namely, that accountId would always have a value) and threw an exception as a result; Nick patched up the three relevant occurrences of this error, and now these profiles should be viewable again.