# Missing search form on /search page when logged in

Tags: bug, search

The search form is **missing from the source code** of the default search page on Main (https://stackoverflow.com/search) when we are logged in. I'm suspecting this is due to recent layout changes?

On Meta, this is not an issue https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search

---

Unregistered/Not logged in, there's the search form:

[image]

Logged in users, missing search form:

[image]

---

I'm on Windows 10, Chrome 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (32-bit), tested with userscripts and userstyles disabled.

FWIW, I don't think this has anything to do with a userscript or browser, as the form is actually missing from the source code.

Meta, `form#bigsearch` is there:

[image]

Main, missing form, empty div:

[image]

Comment: I’m logged in and `https://stackoverflow.com/search` does show the search form on Firefox Nightly 66.0a1. Did you also test with all add-ons (e.g. ad blockers) disabled?

Comment: Yeah, very weird, I can even repro this on IE11 and FF64 (no extensions/ad-blockers), as well as on Chrome Android (separate network, no extensions)

Comment: Another moderator is also unable to see this form, so this is probably a mod-only issue.

Comment: I can also reproduce. Including the infinite flags in the queue.

Comment: I'm not a mod here, but on other sites... and this is broken for me too. But only on SO.

Comment: I had a deja vu of [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/378468/2821954) bug...

Comment: I'm not a mod here or on other network sites, also in a team, and can reproduce (minus the flags of course). stackoverflow.com/search is blank for me too. Tested with Firefox 64.0 on Windows 10 Latest

Comment: Me as well, Chrome on Mac OS High Sierra.

Comment: Perhaps a team-related issue then? I also can't see  the search bar, and I'm not a mod anywhere either. I am part of a  team though. Tested on Chrome 71 on Mac OS High Sierra.

Comment: Blank for me too (member of three Channels); Chrome 68 (64-bit) on Ubuntu 16.04. And is that flag count really so different from normal, @BhargavRao? ;)

Comment: @Mithrandir it switches to infinity once the queue crosses 3,000...

Comment: This is not reproducable on FF 65.0b9 Android in desktop or mobile modes: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7DRZ.jpg

Comment: I think we have sufficient sources to confirm this as a Teams bug. Thanks everyone :)